# Laravel Registration event taking multiple seconds, even though QUEUE_CONNECTION is set to database

Tags: php, laravel

On my local, the following event is taking several seconds:

```
event(new Registered($user));
```

On production, it's even worse.

So it would seem I'm not queueing through the correct mechanism, even though I:

- set the QUEUE_CONNECTION variable in the .env file to "database"
- updated config/queue.php to default to "database"

I'd say I'd make sure to add:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
```

to the event class, but Registered is a framework class. I do find it odd though that this framework class doesn't have these imported, though I'm guessing there's some kind of default magic there.

I've tried running a querying the job table as the queue is processing, and it doesn't appear it's getting any jobs to run. So I'm unsure on my next steps to get this working. Any thoughts?

Thanks, J

Comment: You probably don't want this event to be queued. Remove the `ShouldQueue` stuff.

Comment: I didn't add the ShouldQueue, since that would have to be done in the framework. But why wouldn't I want to? I'm assuming the registration validation email is what's taking up the most time; I'm not sure what else would make Registered($user) take up multiple seconds.

Comment: Queues are, by their nature, not instant; your queue system could be processing a bunch of jobs in front of it, and the polling-based queue listeners can take 10-30 seconds to pick up a new job sometimes. Your question's text focuses a lot on queues; why do you think the queues are relevant here if you havent made the event queueable?

Comment: What do you have on the job or listener? Are you using a 3rd party validator? You need to add more info, anything could be happening here

Comment: @matiaslauriti well it's a standard Laravel job, which I believe just sends out a validation email.

Comment: @ceejayoz, I don't need to the queue to be instant. I need the registration action to be quick. For instance, when someone goes to register (using the standard Laravel breeze), it's taking 15 seconds for the page to come back. And I've narrowed it down to the event(new Registered($user)), which is a standard event for breeze/laravel, and not something I coded.

Comment: You need to dig into why that's slow, then, because that's very not-normal. Something like https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar may help see where the time is going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the issue of the Laravel registration event taking multiple seconds, even though
you've configured the QUEUE_CONNECTION to use the database driver,
you need to ensure that the event is indeed queued and processed asynchronously. Below,
I'll provide you with a step-by-step solution and code examples to help you resolve this problem.

**Configuration:**
Ensure that your .env file is correctly configured to use the database queue driver:

`QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`

Also, verify your config/queue.php file to ensure that the database driver is set as the default:

`default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'database'),`
Custom Event Class:
Create a custom event class for the registration event if you haven't already. This class should implement the ShouldQueue interface to indicate that it should be queued for asynchronous processing. Laravel's built-in Registered event doesn't implement this interface, so you need to create a custom event.

`php artisan make:event CustomRegisteredEvent`

In your CustomRegisteredEvent class, make sure it implements the ShouldQueue interface:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class CustomRegisteredEvent extends RegisteredEvent implements ShouldQueue
{
        // ...
}
```

**Dispatch the Custom Event:**

In your registration controller or wherever you're triggering the event, dispatch the custom event instead of  the built-in Registered event:

`event(new CustomRegisteredEvent($user));`

**Start Queue Worker:**
On your production server, you need to run a queue worker to process the queued jobs. Use a process manager
like Supervisor to keep the queue worker running in the background:

```php
php artisan config:cache
php artisan optimize:clear
composer dump-autoload
 
php artisan queue:work
```

Ensure that the queue worker is actively processing jobs.

**Monitor the Queue:**
You can monitor the status of your queue and the jobs being processed using the following command:

`php artisan queue:status`

**Retry Failed Jobs:**

If any jobs fail during processing, Laravel provides mechanisms to
retry failed jobs. You can use  the php artisan queue:retry command to
retry  specific failed jobs.

**Run below command**

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan optimize:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Thanks @WebDesk, I didn't realize that the Registered event (and all events) wasn't Queued by default.